# Spring JMS - showing list of subscriber or receive() request

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-classic, publish-subscribe

I'm using Spring-JMS with AcriveMQ and i've a short question:
Is it possible to see all subscriber in a kind of list? And/Or is it possible to show all running threads polling on the receive() method?

thanks stetro

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could use JMX to get all subscibers of a specific topic.
The information you will get is a bit limited though. Look at the jconsole listing attached

[image: jconsole example]

Comment: Thank you very much! but there is'nt an info about who is listening ?

Comment: Well, no. But you can manually set the ClientId to something more crisp when you create the connection `connection.setClientID("AMQClientThread_1")` etc. Then you can easily identify which subscriber is active.

Comment: A well, but is this possible with jmsTemaplate? Or can i config this in applicationContext?

Comment: Jmstemplates are à bit limited in this sense. You could work around it by using a SingleConnectionFactory (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/connection/SingleConnectionFactory.html) for each jmstemplate/thread. You can set the clientid on that one